# Conda environment defaults to Python 2 even though Python 3 specified during creation

Tags: python, python-3.x, conda, miniconda

I'm trying to create a conda environment that will use python 3.8 as the default. I created an environment with the following command:

`conda create --name foo python=3.8`

Then after executing `conda activate foo`, the default is still python 2.7:

```
python --version
2.7.6
```

The steps seem so simple but what is going wrong here?

Additional info:
`which python` gives `/usr/bin/python` and `type conda` prints `conda is a shell function from /opt/miniconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh`

Activation has worked in the past

Comment: What is `which python`? What is `type conda`? Has activation worked in the past? What shell is used (things like tmux and screen can impact PATH manipulation)?

Comment: Added info for your first few questions. I'm using the zsh attached to VS Code. I don't know what tmux or screen refer to

Comment: See the proposed duplicate. Feel free to ping me if that doesn't resolve it and I can reopen. Basically, it's a VSCode thing and many have encounter this before.